# Rails/Heroku The page you were looking for doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, url-routing

I'm getting the "The page you were looking for doesn't exist" error from Heroku.
App runs fine in development and production, but no go on Heroku.

"heroku logs" suggests a routing issue with `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):` I've included *config/routes.rb* and results of *heroku logs*, also my *Gemfile*.

**config/routes.rb**

```
    Foodsterbater::Application.routes.draw do
      get "/welcome/index"
      get "static_pages/home"
      get "static_pages/about"
      get "static_pages/contact"
      resources :gigs

      resources :users

      root 'welcome#index'
    end
```

**Heroku logs**

```
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862756+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862732+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862754+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862770+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862772+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862774+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862792+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-27T04:58:51.859086+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 67.160.237.167 at 2014-05-27 04:58:51 +0000
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862666+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862691+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862733+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862758+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862778+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.859100+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 67.160.237.167 at 2014-05-27 04:58:51 +0000
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862693+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862752+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862768+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862783+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862653+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862681+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862737+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862762+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862785+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862668+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862683+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862748+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862776+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862787+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862670+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862715+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862750+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862767+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862780+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862790+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862674+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862687+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862744+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862765+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862789+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862676+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862689+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862735+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862761+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-05-27T04:58:51.862782+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.490117+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=gentle-shelf-817
2.herokuapp.com request_id=7bd56a2d-92ed-4fff-8809-4d0fdbbc356f fwd="67.160.237.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=35ms status=404 bytes=1616
2014-05-27T05:19:10.491972+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 67.160.237.167 at 2014-05-27 05:19:10 +0000
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495303+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495305+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.491984+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 67.160.237.167 at 2014-05-27 05:19:10 +0000
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495297+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495300+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495307+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495312+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495355+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495352+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495353+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495310+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495313+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495322+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495317+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495325+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495350+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495308+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495356+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495361+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495368+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495390+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495315+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495320+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495363+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495379+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495359+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495380+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495318+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495377+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495370+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495386+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495373+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495383+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495376+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495385+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495362+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495371+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495388+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `ca
ll'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495415+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495323+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495358+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495375+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495382+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495411+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495412+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495409+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495406+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495391+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495418+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495408+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495420+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-05-27T05:19:10.495414+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
```

**Gemfile**

```
   group :test do
      gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
      gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
    end

    gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
    gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
    gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
    gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
    gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

    group :doc do
      gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
    end

    group :production do
      gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
      gem 'unicorn'
      gem 'rails_log_stdout',           github: 'heroku/rails_log_stdout'
      gem 'rails3_serve_static_assets', github: 'heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets'
    end

                                                                     35,0-1        Bot
```

Comment: Have you ran your migrations using heroku rake db:migrate ?

Comment: did you commit the routes to your repo before pushing the repo to Heroku?

Comment: I ran rake db:migrate as well as heroku run rake db:migrate. Everything was committed and pushed.

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar problem; however, after changing 1 line code of production.rb located in config/environments/production.rb from

```
config.assets.compile = false
to

config.assets.compile = true
```

commit the new change.

Comment: This was not the problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

I would personally say this is your error:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "/welcome/index"
```

What is this trying to achieve exactly? All you're going to do is send any request for `domain.com/welcome/index` to a non-existent controller

I would change your routes to this:

```
   #config/routes.rb
   Foodsterbater::Application.routes.draw do
      resources :gigs, :users
      resources :static_pages, only: [] do
           get :home
           get :about
           get :contact
      end
      root 'welcome#index'
    end
```

Comment: No problem! Anything else you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, but I'm not positive how. I adjusted my routes as suggested above, but I was also making some git mistakes. I thought I was working from the master branch, but I think I was working from a branch and not merging before pushing. Took some re-reading of git documentation to get it figured out. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging